Interpolate the Polyphase data flow using polyphase FIR filter
Suppose we have a system that processes two data branches, $x_1=[11,14]$ and $x_2 =[12,13]$ in polyphase, with a system clock running at 2 Hz. We determine the FIR filter coefficients, which total 8, and since we want to interpolate by a factor of 2, we choose a half-band FIR filter to reduce calculations.
With a system clock of 2 Hz, and given 2 input branches that will be upsampled by a factor of 2, the system’s output will consist of 4 branches, each containing 2 sets of data. These input data, will effectively represent a rate of 4 Hz. However, as the system cannot handle frequencies above 2 Hz, we apply a polyphase structure to manage the data flow.
How can I design a polyphase FIR filter for these data set?
From what I understand, I need to combine the filter coefficients with the input and output data, summing them to produce the final output. This would result in 4 branches, each containing 2 upsampled values of the original input, giving a total effective rate of 8 Hz.
Now, if I want to divide the FIR filter into 4 polyphases, how should I approach the design?
0
This is a simplified version of a signal that is split into two branches. These two signals together give us the complete representation of the original signal, known as polyphase data flow. However, previous discussions didn’t specify whether this involves a 2-phase polyphase data flow.
As far as I understand, I need to divide the filter coefficients across the filter bank and sum them somehow to obtain four branches of data. Each branch should consist of two sampled data points, which together represent values between 11 and 14.
For example, the output of the signal might look something like this (just using random numbers):
$y_1 = [11, 11.5]$
$y_2 = [12, 0]$
$y_3 = [13, 0]$
$y_4 = [0, 14]$
This output means the data set is successfully upsampled by a factor of 2, as each output represents 8 samples in total.

I believe you question is already answered here: How to implement Polyphase filter?.

WTF does this mean: x1=[11,14] and x2 =[12,13]  ???  Is this two signals both with only two samples?
